# How come stored procedure will not create table with IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures

```
USE [WORKFILES]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[MLINT]    Script Date: 05/04/2015 16:49:38 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MLINT]

AS

IF OBJECT_ID('WORKFILES.dbo.MLINT05', 'U') IS NULL

BEGIN
        --CREATE CMPDTE TABLE
CREATE TABLE WORKFILES.dbo.MLINT05
(DTSTAMP DATETIME NOT NULL)
END

BEGIN
        --INSERT TIMESTAMP
INSERT INTO WORKFILES.dbo.MLINT05
SELECT (getdate())
END

BEGIN
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20), DTSTAMP)
FROM [WORKFILES].[dbo].[MLINT05]
END
```

I added a go to my SP

```
USE [WORKFILES]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[MLINT]    Script Date: 05/04/2015 16:49:38 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MLINT]

AS

IF OBJECT_ID('WORKFILES.dbo.MLINT05') IS NULL
GO

BEGIN
        --CREATE CMPDTE TABLE
CREATE TABLE WORKFILES.dbo.MLINT05
(DTSTAMP DATETIME NOT NULL)
END

BEGIN
        --INSERT TIMESTAMP
INSERT INTO WORKFILES.dbo.MLINT05
SELECT (getdate())
END

BEGIN
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20), DTSTAMP)
FROM [WORKFILES].[dbo].[MLINT05]
END
```

Comment: you'll probably have to clarify your question in the body of your post along with adding a few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you get when you run `select OBJECT_ID('WORKFILES.dbo.MLINT05', 'U')`?

Comment: When I select OBJECT_ID('WORKFILES.dbo.MLINT05', 'U') I get (No column name) with 289526398 as the result

Comment: My issue now is once I execute, the table will be created with the getdate inserted. But if I run again, the error message states my table is already in the database and the select statement does not execute.

Comment: Why do you have the extra `BEGIN` and `END` blocks?  Are you trying to make an `IF...THEN...ELSE` statement? Like referenced here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

Comment: This is caused by the way the sql engine works. It will parse your procedure but when it attempts to execute it the engine is smart enough to realize that your table already exists. If you want to do this kind of thing you need to put the create table logic in dynamic sql. And putting GO inside a procedure is NOT going to work. GO is the default batch separator and is not a t-sql statement.

Answer (score 1):

The `go` keyword is used by the Management Studio client to separate batches.  You can't use it in stored procedures.  In fact, if you use `go` in a stored procedure definition in SSMS, the `go` will mark the end of the procedure.

Your procedure works fine in SQL Server 2012.  Perhaps older versions give an error when they see a `create table` for a table that already exists.  If this is true, you can work around that with dynamic SQL:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('WORKFILES.dbo.MLINT05', 'U') IS NULL
    BEGIN
    EXEC (N'CREATE TABLE WORKFILES.dbo.MLINT05 (DTSTAMP DATETIME NOT NULL)')
    END
```

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. After using this IF statement, I am still having trouble having the stored procedure create the table. I added the following: IF OBJECT_ID('WORKFILES.dbo.MLINT05', 'U') IS NULL
    BEGIN
    EXEC (N'CREATE TABLE WORKFILES.dbo.MLINT05 (DTSTAMP DATETIME NOT NULL)')
    END


  --CREATE CMPDTE TABLE
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE WORKFILES.dbo.MLINT05
(DTSTAMP DATETIME NOT NULL)
END


  --INSERT TIMESTAMP
BEGIN
INSERT INTO WORKFILES.dbo.MLINT05
SELECT (getdate())
END

BEGIN
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20), DTSTAMP)
FROM [WORKFILES].[dbo].[MLINT05]
END

Comment: Can you put the `insert` and `select` in an `exec` call?  Note, it is unusual to create tables on the fly, but I assume you have a good reason

Comment: I added the exec call as well as my insert and select statements. But the create, insert and select statements only work when I run them individually.